# css full page background not showing up

Tags: css, image, background

So I followed the tutorial at [http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/][1] 
but nothing shows up! The background is just white!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <style type="css/text">
html {
    background: url(images/black-carbon-sheet.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: `background: url('images/black-carbon-sheet.jpg')` add quotes `'` .

Comment: the quotes are optional

Comment: background: url("images/black-carbon-sheet.jpg") try this

Comment: This works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/3A2Z2/ are you sure your image has the URL you requested?

Comment: @AliBassam Quotes are not needed at all. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

style `type="css/text"` is incorrect

use

style `type="text/css"` or just remove it entirely.

also ensure your image path is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Also, check your path.